# Body length requirement does not mesh with default link name?

Tags: discussion

I see a bit of a problem that you all can perhaps help me with.  When editing a post, if the body length is not 30, the edit cannot be saved.  The default link name "enter link description here" goes a long way to meeting this length, but is not very meaningful in an answer.  If one were to give a meaningful name, it would likely have fewer characters, but may not be accepted because the 30 character limit is no longer met.

What can we do to address this?  If the answer is truly this short, would it then be a candidate for a flag instead of an edit?  I recently noticed over 1400 posts containing the phrase "enter link description here" and fixing some of them like [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756840/how-to-exit-function-in-mvc/11756917#11756917) would not be possible.

Comment: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5911656/398242)

Comment: Yes, I think I already flagged that one.  Hopefully it will be removed soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Link-only answers are *anyway* flaggable (and deletable) as Not An Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). If the `enter link description here` makes a difference, it *probably* is something that ought to be flagged. (or fattened up with some editing)